# How do i change the format of the mysql timestamp from when a user posts something

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

Currently whenever the timestamp is echo'ed it looks like this

```
function show_posts($userid){
$posts = array();
$sql = "select body, stamp from posts where user_id = '$userid' order by stamp desc";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $posts[] = array(   'stamp' => $data->stamp, 
                        'userid' => $userid, 
                        'body' => $data->body
                );
}
return $posts;
}
```

i want to take this stamp and change it so instead of printing 2012-03-26 12:07:52
it will print the day followed by the time etc. below is how i show it on my webpage.

```
<?php
        foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
            echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
            echo "<td>".$list['userid'] ."</td>\n";
            echo "<td>".$list['body'] ."<br/>\n";
            echo "<small>".$list['stamp']."<br/>\n <a>Like</a> <a>Flag</a><hr     class='span9'/></small></td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
?>
```

Comment: use the date(format, timestamp) function for that. More infos regarding the format options and how to use the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert the string to a timestamp, then use [`date`](http://php.net/date) to format it how you want.

Comment: I vote this up - simplest way to do it, without complicating your MySQL queries. strtotime() will return a unix timestamp which gives you infinite format options. 

echo date('F d', strtotime($timevarfrommysql)); is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).